# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting IF/Then

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Because I don't know the syntax for google sheets - I would like to add a rule that states:

If the date in col D is today's date or earlier, then col B should populate with the word: Published

Sample Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TWa6QkT1bBc4DxGcNzr5VP4lYsb5m_Zfz3XKI8U4lPs/edit?usp=sharing

IF there are any google sheets users who create custom rules - please advise. TIA.

Comment: What you're trying to do is not "formatting" at all. You actually want output to go somewhere (i.e., you need a formula). But you haven't given enough information to be able to suggest such a formula. Keep in mind that we don't know your spreadsheet, data, data types or end goal. I invite you to share a link to your spreadsheet (or to a copy of it) here, so that we can *see* what you want. It sounds fairly simple; but again, there are too many unknowns right now.

Comment: Thanks, I do realize this isn't formatting, but a formula/rule - conditional formatting is just the menu under where it lies in google sheets *shrug.   

Here is a sample:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TWa6QkT1bBc4DxGcNzr5VP4lYsb5m_Zfz3XKI8U4lPs/edit?usp=sharing

The goal is ultra simple, I just don't know how to write the formula to get there.

Thanks again

Comment: I see that you have the word "Scheduled" in some cells as well; yet your post only mentions what should happen if the Col-D date is less than or equal to the current day's date. So I'm still unclear on the goal. If you want a formula to produce results in Col B, then you can't *also* manually enter data. So you can *either* have a formula *or* manual entry. If there is a standard set of rules for *all* cells in Col B, then one formula can do it. However, if you want formula-produced results that you can overwrite per cell, it will have to be individual formulas in every cell of Col B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a new sheet ("Erik Help") with this formula:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(D:D="",,IF(D:D<=TODAY(), "Published", "Scheduled")))`

Seems to be what you needed in the end.